# Unexpected results when decoding Unicode Escape Sequences

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have this black box that spits out a JSON, and this file comes with what *I assume*, are escaped Unicode characters. Here's a snippet:

```
{
    "AR_DESCRI":"LIMA CENTIMETRADA\/FORMAS U\u00c3\u2018AS 100\/180 MANI."
}
```

Now, here's how the resulting JSON should actually look like to any reasonable human being:

```
{
    "AR_DESCRI":"LIMA CENTIMETRADA/FORMAS UÑAS 100/180 MANI."
}
```

The most importat thing there is that `\u00c3\u2018` should equal the `Ñ` character.

However as you can check from any Unicode Escape Sequence decoder, this is not the case, the ouput for `\u00c3\u2018` is actually `Ã‘` which is basically random noise.

I've tried some [**online decoders**](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) and I've also used the `json_decode()` PHP functions, which is the enviroment I'm currently working on. Both give me the same results. Here's the snippet of code if you are curious:

```
<?php
$json = '{"AR_DESCRI":"LIMA CENTIMETRADA\/FORMAS U\u00c3\u2018AS 100\/180 MANI."}';
print_r(json_decode($json));

//Output: stdClass Object ( [AR_DESCRI] => LIMA CENTIMETRADA/FORMAS UÃ‘AS 100/180 MANI. )
```

So my question is, why on earth does this happen, is it an encoding issue on the black box's side? Am I using the wrong function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Ñ` is `U+00D1` represented in UTF8 as the literal bytes `\xc3\x91`.

What you've got there is [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) caused by incorrectly forcing a cp1252-to-UTF conversion on the input string where in cp1252 `\xc3` is `Ã` and `\x91` is `‘`. [left single-quote]

These are then converted into their UTF equivalent escapes as the `\u00c3\u2018` you see.

Proof:

```
function ordify($str) {
    return implode(' ', array_map(
        function($a){return sprintf('U+%04x', mb_ord($a));},
        preg_split('//u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
    ));
}

$borked = 'Ã‘';
$fixed  = mb_convert_encoding($borked, 'cp1252', 'utf-8');

var_dump(
    $borked, ordify($borked),
    $fixed,  ordify($fixed)
);
```

Output:

```
string(5) "Ã‘"
string(13) "U+00c3 U+2018"
string(2) "Ñ"
string(6) "U+00d1"
```

So go fix the thing that's generating your JSON, because *any reasonable human being* should value producing valid data in the first place over kludging in a bandaid solution.

Comment: Complete answer, though you can lose the pedantry. If I could modify the black box I wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: So far I've done a `json_decode()` to unescape the unicode sequences, but then again `mb_convert_encoding()` expects a string, should I iterate through the array and convert each entry manually or do a `json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` to get an unescaped string back and then input it to `mb_convert_encoding()`? Is there a more straightforward way of achieving this without touching the black box?